# Jekyll data file best practices: in /data, or inside post front matter?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I started experimenting with embedding data inside a post's front matter & really like this alternative to standalone data files (in /data). This is especially true for small-to-medium datasets, for example project notes in outline form.

Are there any downsides to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are available for you purposes. Choose what you like more.